# Deploying ASP.NET Core to linux -- avoiding 50 MB deploy?

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, coreclr, asp.net5

I am able to deploy CoreCLR ASP.NET apps to Linux and have them run, hurray. To do this I am using

`dnu publish --no-source -o <dest-dir>`

which gives me a dest-dir full of many CoreCLR packages, one of which is a package for my published app specifically.

This folder is pretty big, around 50 MB for the simple Web Application Basic (no auth) described at https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-app-using-vscode/ .

Is there a sensible way to deploy to Linux without pushing so much around? Can I get rid of a bunch of those CoreCLR packages somehow? Is there a good way of deploying source-only and doing the work on the server (I may have seen something about this, but I lost it if I did)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already publishing without runtime (`--runtime` option on `dnu publish`) which reduces the bundle size significantly.

You need to get somehow those packages on the server. Even if you deploy only the sources, you'll have to restore which will download the same amount of packages. Also, running from sources makes the application start significantly slower (depending on the number of dependencies).

However, if you publish the entire bundle once and you app's dependencies don't change, you can upload only the folders corresponding to your projects, instead of re-uploading all the dependencies.

Comment: I was wondering about `dnu restore` and may still try it since my upload speed is slow. However, if it is not surfacing as a best practice I'll feel free to experiment.